# How can I convert this long-running background task to async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have code that is kicking off work on a long-running background task with a heartbeat. The application is being updated to use async/await and I am having problems updating this code to follow suite. Here is the code, roughly:

```
private void StartBackgroundTasks(CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSrc)
{
    void TaskAction()
    {
        DoWork();
    }

    void HeartbeatAction()
    {
        var task = TaskFactory.CreateAndStartLongRunningTask(
            TaskAction, cancelTokenSrc.Token);

        while (true)
        {
            // checks Task.Status to figure out when to stop
            if (!TryPerformHeartbeat(task)) break;

            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Wait();
        }
    }

    TaskFactory.CreateAndStartLongRunningTask(HeartbeatAction);
}
```

And here is how the long-running tasks are being started:

```
internal static class TaskFactory
{
    internal static Task CreateAndStartLongRunningTask(
        Action action, CancellationToken? token = null)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            action,
            token ?? CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

From what I understand I need to:

- pass a `Func<Task>` to `CreateAndStartLongRunningTask`
- change `StartNew` to take `async () => await taskFunc()` instead of `action`
- add async/awaits up through the method signatures as needed

What would be the correct way to get this code runs on a background thread and allows for the async/await pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Essentially in short unless you specifically need it you shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. Just use `Task.Run` like so:

```cs
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await TryPerformHeartbeat();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

    }
}, token);
```

These two articles are helpful in explaining why:
http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/ and https://sergeyteplyakov.github.io/Blog/async/2019/05/21/The-Dangers-of-Task.Factory.StartNew.html

Comment: Good answer. Side note: passing the `token` here is useless; it was also useless in the original code.

Comment: @StephenCleary could you provide more information on why the token is/was useless? The code posted is incomplete, the token is used to provide a timeout and or cancellation if the long running logic uses it cooperatively.

Comment: @yenta: Passing the token *to `Task.Run`* is useless, because it only cancels the starting of the task, which starts right away. Passing it to your inner delegate is appropriate.

Comment: what you can do is to check before every delay if the token was canceled and then break out of the while(true)

Comment: @StephenCleary hah, now i see